Manipulating React DOM(input) from outside React Scope , Using a JS script
function translateInputText(targetLang) {

    const inputElement = document.querySelector('the id of the html element');

    if (inputElement) {
        const originalText = inputElement.innerText;
        console.log("Original text:", originalText);

        // Prepare the translation request URL
        const url = "my translation api url"

        fetch(url)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                if (data.data && data.data.translations.length > 0) {
                    const translatedText = data.data.translations[0].translatedText;
 const selection = window.getSelection();
                    const range = document.createRange();
                    range.selectNodeContents(inputElement);
                    range.collapse(false); // Collapse to the end of the content
                    selection.removeAllRanges();
                    selection.addRange(range);

                  
                    document.execCommand('insertText', false, translatedText);

                } else {
                    console.warn("No translation available for input text.");
                }
            })
            .catch(error => console.error("Translation error for input text:", error));
    } else {
        console.error("Input element not found.");
    }
}


this seems to add the the new word beside the exisiting word i extracted from a react input field
i tried
   inputElement.textContent = '';
   inputElement.textContent = translatedText;

and
    inputElement.innerHTML = '';
    inputElement.innerHTML = translatedText;
    const event = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });
    inputElement.dispatchEvent(event);
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    const range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(inputElement);
    range.collapse(false); // Collapse to the end of the content
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);

None of these seem to work
The ultimate goal is to remove the entire input text and replace with our text ,
